# Using Osmosis to filter OSM XML tags

Tags: xml, filter, tags, openstreetmap

I am working with .osm files and am trying to filter entities based on tags. I need to view only entities containing both source and attribution tags. I used the following to successfully filter all source tags only:

```
osmosis --read-xml file = "northern_ireland.osm" --way-key-value keyValueList="source" --used node --write-xml northern_ireland_source.osm
```

From another tutorial, I've noticed that I would need to use a pipe: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Detailed_Usage_0.38

So I did the following:

```
osmosis --rx northern_ireland.osm --accept-ways source=* outPipe.0 = SOURCE
```

However, upon trying such code, I get a syntax error stating: Argument does not contain a name before the '=' (i.e. name = value).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

first there may not be an space before and after the "=":

```
outPipe.0=SOURCE
```

second IIRC outPipe.0 is an argument of --rx:

```
osmosis --read-xml file="northern_ireland.osm" outPipe.0="SOURCE" \
--tf accept-ways source=* inPipe.0="SOURCE" outPipe.0="step1" \
--tf accept-ways attribution=* inPipe.0="step1" outPipe.0="step2" \
--write-xml file="northern_ireland_source.osm" inPipe.0="step2"
```

that may work.
but it isn't tested.
its a little time ago since i used that pipes ;)